# The chain mystery

Tags: chain

A day I was in front of this...

[image]

The person was actually trying to change the tire but this chain knot keeps haunting me.
The chain has crossed the frame bar... and the most unbelievable, he could manage to pass the chain through a chain loop.
He didn't disassemble the chain as the next day, he had to buy a tool.
I really wonder how possible is to do that. Any idea?
Anyone already experienced such thing?

Comment: The chain hasn't cross the frame bar, it has always been installed that way. It normally goes through the hole between a chain stay, seat stay and the seat tube.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any magic here - the chain fell off the chainring and because the derailleur was unscrewed, it dropped to the bottom. Then the derailleur got twisted a couple of times around the cable and here's the end result.

As to how's that possible... Well, all kinds of mishaps can occur if you don't know how to do it right, as is clearly the case here. The chain could easily be removed altogether without hassle as there's a master link clearly visible in the photo.

Answer (score 6):

The chain can be untangled by carefully inceasing the diameter of loops you see till the adjacent loops join, simplifying the pattern. Contra-intuitively these loops cannot be removed by just trying to pull the chain in the attempt to make it straight. There was never a need for me to split the chain just to untangle it.

Comment: Storytime - I once found a stranded rider who had managed to put two loops in his chain while riding, and then sucked one of the loops through the front derailleur before stopping.   There was no way we could undo the loops without dropping the chain off - could not force the double-thickness back through the front derailleur with hand pressure and roadside tools.